# Odd large font size in reputation tab on profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web, reputation-history

When viewing my recent reputation changes on Stack Overflow via my profile, I see some entries with a much larger font size. This seems like a formatting mistake; the size reverts to normal again when scrolling down to where the reputation changes for the next day begin.

This is on mobile, using Firefox on an iPhone 12 Mini (IOS 16.1)

[image: Screenshot from mobile]

It may not be obvious after my edits, but some *short* question titles are rendered using the smaller font in the rest of the listing.

Comment: FYI, the blur job is see-through. Not sure if that's important to you or not, but you'll probably want to use something less see-through if you want to actually hide the titles

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Nah, I didn't want the text to distract from the question but it's not particularly secret.

Comment: This happens all over the site on mobile, comments used to be terrible for it, chat is too